# Is Strider Hiryu manga considered as canon?

Tags: game-history, strider-hiryu

After playing *Strider* on PS3, and using Strider Hiryu across all *Marvel vs Capcom* games, I have become aware that he, like most game characters, have manga that delve into his past and life in his world outside the game.

Are these manga considered canon? Or are the games the only canon materials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the *Strider Hiryu* manga is canon.

The manga series was created by the artist group, Moto Kikaku, in collaboration with Capcom. Since Capcom is credited with the game's creation, the collaboration result with the creator is considered canon.

The manga was serialized from **May to October 1988**, while the first Strider Hiryu game, Strider (CPS-1) was released in **March 1989**.
The manga serves as an *origins* story of the lead character Hiryu.

Source: [Strider Wikia](http://strider.wikia.com/wiki/Strider_Hiryu_(Manga))

Comment: I bet it's nigh impossible to find a copy either with it being so old. It's like a collectible now. Know of any sources senpai?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know of any means to obtain physical copies of the manga.

Comment: Digital maybe? If not at least senpai noticed me. This brings me joy :-)

Comment: A quick search in Google with the keywords can you bring you the result, though be warned, not all are legal~

Comment: Arigatou nee!!!!